# azure redirect all http to https

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, azure

I am trying to do redirect all http://mysite.cloudapp.net requests to https://mysite.cloudapp.net

to do this I added the following to my web.config as it is pasted below.
But http requests are not getting redirected to https . Please help me find out what am I doing wrong .Do I need to replace the {SERVER_NAME} with my https url ?

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite xdt:Transform="Insert">
        <rules>
            <rule name="RedirectToHTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{SERVER_NAME}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

My https url is working file

if I directly try https url ,its working perfectly fine,but in case if my users are typing http by mistake ,I want them to be redirected automatically to https ,this is what I am trying to achieve here .But this is not happening now.

Comment: Have you configured HTTPS endpoint in your role's setting? Also, I don't think you can procure a SSL certificate for `cloudapp.net` domain. You need to get your own custom domain and do a CNAME mapping to yoursite.cloudapp.net domain.

Comment: absolute correct post as answer to get accepted!

Comment: if I directly try https url ,its working perfectly fine,but in case if my users are typing http by mistake ,I want them to be redirected automatically to https ,this is what I am trying to achieve here .But this is not happening now.

Comment: @Lee - Did you solve this issue? My site is stuck in loading if I try with `http` but succeeds if I do it with `https`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.NET MVC you can try [RequireHttps] attribute as mentioned in this [article](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/redirecting-to-https-in-windows-azure-two-methods).

Here is the default rule for http to https conversion in IIS URL Rewrite module.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Found" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```